# PDFsharp mm size is smaller when printed

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, pdfsharp

I need to print an image on a PDF file, that when printed, is exactly 80 mm high. I know the page sizes, I know the DPI of the image I am putting on the PDF. But when i print it, it comes out at 78.5 mm... and the task I am doing needs to be exact.

I load the image from disk, I know the DPI and I know the pixel height/width. I load it into an Image object (setting the vertical and horizontal dpi to 300). And then add it to he PDF.

```
    public static void SavePdf(Image img, string filename)
        {
            // Create a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            document.Info.Title = "Test";

            // Create an empty page
            PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
            page.Width = SharedMethods.MmToPixel(520);
            page.Height = SharedMethods.MmToPixel(110);

            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            XImage image = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);

            gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);

            // Save the document...

            document.Save(filename);


        }
```

The image has to start at the top left of the page.

But it seems to start a few mm in from the top, and seems to reduce in size from 80 mm to 78.5.

I heard PDFs resize by 98% due to ... something. Can this be the issue and I need to upscale my image to 102%?

Note, I know the mm size I want, so I convert that to pixels based on my DPI and a constant I found online:

```
 const double milimetresPerInch = 25.4; // as one inch is 25.4 mm
 const double dpi = 300;

 public static int MmToPixel(double mm)
 {
     double pixel = mm * dpi / milimetresPerInch;
     return (int)Math.Round(pixel);
 }
```

Edit:

I am using the XUnit.FromMillimeter now, but is this correct?

```
page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter(520);
page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter(110);
```

I am then loading the image, which is the same size as the paper size (in mm) like this:

```
XImage image = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);
gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);
```

Is that right? It should fit the entire page, but I notice I am using pixels, but maybe I need to use FromPixels or somehow, FromMillimteres?

Comment: When you print the PDF, what is the size of the actual paper it is printed on and what are the print(dialog) settings?

Comment: The paper is a custom sized paper of 520mm by 110mm. The rest of the printer dialog settings are left as default.

Comment: How is the scaling in the print dialog configured?

Comment: In the call to `DrawImage` you should use `page.Width` instead of `image.PixelWidth` (similar for height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard PDFs resize by 98% due to ... something.

Sources for that info?

Printers often have non-print areas, typically a few mm on each side with modern printers. By default Adobe Reader reduces the page size while printing to fit the whole page into the printing area. Disable automatic scaling when printing with Adobe Reader.
If the image starts at the top left position, parts of the image may be cut-off due to the non-printing area.

Adobe Reader can measure items on the PDF page. Thus you can easily verify whether your image has the dimensions it should have, This will tell you whether there is a problem with printing or with embedding the image into the PDF.
Adobe Reader can also show you the size of the page - maybe the page has a different mm size than you expect.

You should use PDFsharp's methods like `Unit.FromMillimeter` to convert units. Your method `MmToPixel` may do more harm than good. PDF pages do not have pixel and measurements are in points.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That might be it then. I'm using the free version of acrobats PDF viewer and can't seem to validate that my box is indeed 80mm high. Is there a way to validate this? I'll also look for the setting to stop the resizing.

Comment: I'm unsure how to use the Unit.FromMillimeter. How would the line, "page.Height = SharedMethods.MmToPixel(110);" be switched to use the built in method?

Comment: I have added an edit to the bottom of the initial question, taking into account your suggestions. The function I use to convert mm to pixels is now only used when I render the actual graphic. When I place it on the pdf, I am using the XUnit.FromMillimeters as shown in the initial question edit. But I am stuck on the placement of the image.